# Android WebView pause sound on Activity onPause

Tags: android-webview

Background music from WebView keep playing when a user hits the home button. I am testing that on an Android 8.0 phone.

I have tried multiple solution from other thread (also tried using reflection as suggested on some threads). Unfortunately, nothing has worked for me. I am calling `webview.onPause()`.

Is there any up to date solutions that are not listed on other threads that you can help me with?